# Resources for basics of lattice crypto

Tags: lattice-crypto

I'm looking to fill in the gaps of my knowledge of lattices. Can anyone point me towards papers or books that introduce lattice crypto assuming a fairly solid math background?

Mods: Feel free to close this if it's not the proper format. I'm not exactly clear on the literature request policy.

Comment: Bar-Ilan University ran a [Winter School on Lattice-based Crypto](http://crypto.biu.ac.il/winterschool2012/) a year or so ago. There are a number of videos there from some of the top researchers in the field. That said, reference/literature requests are off-topic, so I'll have to close the question. Hopefully the info you have received is helpful though.

Comment: No problem. Looks like there's plenty to go on, thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [introduction](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~daniele/papers/FOSAD11.pdf) and [this one](https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/pqc.pdf) are well formed . Also have a look at this [thesis](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/pgrad/csjhvdp/files/ThesisJvdPol.pdf) . Notes from this [course](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~nigel/FHE-MPC/) may be helpful . [Oded Regev](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/) has numerous publications to the field.